# Proper use of 'forestall'. Is this allowed?

Tags: sentence

> Your attitude always forestalls us from enjoying.

Does the above sentence make sense?

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'your attitude always forestalls us from enjoying ourselves.'?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is really a correct use of *forestalls*.

[Forestalls](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forestall) means to take measures *in advance* to prevent something. An attitude is a disposition in the moment, so if it's attitude that is the problem, it would be strange for that to be premeditated.

I think what you want is *hinders*. Also, as mentioned by others, you can't end on "enjoying" as you did. I think this is what you want to say:

> Your attitude hinders our enjoyment of what we are doing.

Replace "what we are doing" with the specific thing you are talking about.

Comment: Take measure in advance. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

As far as *forestalls* is concerned, yes, but you either need to say *enjoyment* or add the subject of the enjoyment:

> Your attitude always forestalls *our enjoyment*.
>   Your attitude always forestalls us from enjoying *Monopoly*.

---

Edit:  I believe *[forestalls](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forestall)* works according to this definition:

> 4: to exclude, hinder, or prevent by prior occupation or measures

Comment: Your attitude forestalls us from enjoying our time.